# How to use inheritance to level up a character

Tags: python-3.x, oop, object, inheritance

```
# Import Modules
from Dice import dice
d10 = dice(10,1) #I use dice, but you could just as easily use random.randint()
d4 = dice(4,1)
d20 = dice(20,1)

# Assign Classes
class Player_Character:
    inventory = []
    def __init__(self, HP, MaxHP, AC, ToHitAdjustment, Surprise_Adjustment, 
                 Initiative_Adjustment, Exp, \
                 MaxExp, Gold, Damage):
        self.HP = int(HP)
        self.MaxHP = int(MaxHP)
        self.AC = int(AC)
        self.ToHitAdjustment = int(ToHitAdjustment)
        self.Surprise_Adjustment = int(Surprise_Adjustment)
        self.Initiative_Adjustment = int(Initiative_Adjustment)
        self.Exp = int(Exp)
        self.MaxExp = int(MaxExp)
        self.Gold = int(Gold)
        self.Damage = int(Damage)
```

this next section may be where the error is, although I doubt it because when I run through the code the character is assigned exp and gold and they seem to grow at the correct rate.

```
    def attack(self, goblin, Player_Character):
        Player_attack_roll = d20.die_roll() + Player_Character.ToHitAdjustment
        if (Player_attack_roll >= goblin.AC):
            print('you did', Player_Character.Damage, 'damage')
            goblin.HP -= Player_Character.Damage
            if (goblin.HP <= 0):
                print("congratulations you killed the goblin")
                Player_Character.Exp += goblin.ExpReward
                if (Player_Character.Exp >= Player_Character.MaxExp):
                    print("Congratulations you have leveled up")
                    Player_Character.LevelUp()
                print('you have', Player_Character.Exp, 'exp ')
                Player_Character.Gold += goblin.Gold
                print("you have", Player_Character.Gold, 'gold ')
                del goblin
        else:
            print("You miss ")

    def flee(self):
        print("you run away ")
        quit()

    def heal(self, Player_Character):
        Player_Character.HP += d10.die_roll()
        if Player_Character.HP >= Player_Character.MaxHP:
            Player_Character.HP = Player_Character.MaxHP
            print("You have reached max HP ")
```

this may be where the error is, I expect it to assign the variable name 'MrHezy' which was previously assigned to Player_Character to FighterLvl1, but when I run the code it continuously says that I am leveling up, which I am unsure if that means that the character is remaining as Player_Character, or if there is something else wrong

```
    def LevelUp(self):
        MrHezy = FighterLvl1(25, 25, 15, 10, 2, 2, 25, 75, 20, d10.die_roll()+5)
```

This next section has code is where my question of inheritance comes into play. Even though FighterLvl1 has inherited from (Player_Character) my IDE says things like "unresolved attribute reference 'Exp' for FighterLvl1" Also I am unsure if adding the 'attack' method under FighterLvl1 does anything; I expect it to overwrite the 'attack' method from Player_Character

```
class FighterLvl1(Player_Character):
    def attack(self, goblin, Player_Character):
        Player_attack_roll = d20.die_roll() + Player_Character.ToHitAdjustment
        if (Player_attack_roll >= goblin.AC):
            print('you did', Player_Character.Damage, 'damage')
            goblin.HP -= Player_Character.Damage
            if (goblin.HP <= 0):
                print("congratulations you killed the goblin")
                FighterLvl1.Exp += goblin.ExpReward
                if (FighterLvl1.Exp >= FighterLvl1.MaxExp):
                    print("Congratulations you have leveled up")
                    FighterLvl1.LevelUp()
                print('you have', FighterLvl1.Exp, 'exp ')
                FighterLvl1.Gold += goblin.Gold
                print("you have", FighterLvl1.Gold, 'gold ')
                del goblin
    def LevelUp(self):
        MrHezy = FighterLvl2(Player_Character)

class FighterLvl2(Player_Character):
    def LevelUp(self):
        MrHezy = FighterLvl3(Player_Character)

class FighterLvl3(Player_Character):
    def MaxLevel(self):
        print("Congratulations you are level 3, this is the highest programmed level in the game 
               ")

class goblin:
    def __init__(self, HP, MaxHP, AC, ToHitAdjustment, Surprise_Adjustment, 
                 Initiative_Adjustment, \
                 ExpReward, Gold, Damage):
        self.HP = int(HP)
        self.MaxHP = int(MaxHP)
        self.AC = int(AC)
        self.ToHitAdjustment = int(ToHitAdjustment)
        self.Surprise_Adjustment = int(Surprise_Adjustment)
        self.Initiative_Adjustment = int(Initiative_Adjustment)
        self.ExpReward = int(ExpReward)
        self.Gold = int(Gold)
        self.Damage = int(Damage)

    def attack(self, Player_Character, goblin):
        if (goblin.HP <= 0):
            print("the goblin is inert")
        else:
            goblin_attack_roll = d20.die_roll() + goblin.ToHitAdjustment
            if (goblin_attack_roll >= Player_Character.AC):
                goblin_damage = d4.die_roll()
                print("you take", goblin_damage, 'damage')
                Player_Character.HP -= goblin_damage
                if (Player_Character.HP <= 0):
                    print("oh dear you have died")
                    del Player_Character
                    quit()
            else:
                print("the goblin misses ")

MrHezy = Player_Character(20, 20, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, d10.die_roll())


def spawn_goblin(goblin):
    G1 = goblin(5, 10, 8, 2, 0, 0, 25, 5, d4.die_roll())
    return G1

goblin1 = spawn_goblin(goblin)

def battle(goblin1):

    # user input
    player_initiative_adjustment = MrHezy.Initiative_Adjustment
    monster_initiative_adjustment = goblin1.Initiative_Adjustment

    #define while loop for the battle
    while True:
        if (goblin1.HP <= 0):
            print('oh dear looks like we need a new goblin')
            break
        #use random.randint(a,b) to generate player and monster base initiative
        player_base_initiative = d10.die_roll()
        monster_base_initiative = d10.die_roll()

        #subtract the adjustment to get player and monster initiative
        player_initiative = player_base_initiative - player_initiative_adjustment
        monster_initiative = monster_base_initiative - monster_initiative_adjustment

        #compare the initiatives and display the results
        if (player_initiative < monster_initiative):
            attack_flee_heal = input("congratulations you go first. Would you like to attack, 
                                      flee, or heal?")
            if attack_flee_heal == 'attack':
                MrHezy.attack(goblin1, MrHezy)
            elif attack_flee_heal == 'heal':
                MrHezy.heal(MrHezy)
                print("the goblin attacks")
                goblin1.attack(MrHezy)
            elif attack_flee_heal == 'flee':
                MrHezy.flee()
        else:
            print("uhoh, the monsters go first, they attack!")
            goblin1.attack(MrHezy, goblin1)
            attack_flee_heal = input("Would you like to attack, flee, or heal? ")
            if attack_flee_heal == 'attack':
                MrHezy.attack(goblin1, MrHezy)
            elif attack_flee_heal == 'heal':
                MrHezy.heal(MrHezy)
                print("the goblin attacks")
                goblin1.attack(MrHezy, goblin1)
            elif attack_flee_heal == 'flee':
                MrHezy.flee()



#main game loop
while True:
    spawn_goblin(goblin)
    battle(goblin1)
    print("spawn another goblin")
    goblin1.HP = 0
    goblin1.HP += d10.die_roll()
```

This code runs perfectly well, please enter it into your IDE.
The problem that I have is a logic error, when a goblin is killed instead of leveling up the character first to level 1 then level 2 then level 3 instead the character levels up to level 1 over and over and over.

Comment: in fact im not sure if it is even leveling up to level 1 over and over, it might just be saying that it is...

Comment: When you are copying and pasting this into the IDE after importing the random module you'll need to use ctr+r to find and replace all instances of the die-rolls, ex) for d10 hit ctr+r then type random.randint(1,10)

Comment: * in pycharm IDE press ctrl+r then type d10.die_roll() replace with random.randint(1,10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Danny Varod, in that there are very many improvements that need to be made, and I definitely recommend following his advice.

However if you are simply looking to make what you have work you need to specify in your level up methods that you are referencing the global MrHezy variable.

eg:

```py
def LevelUp(self):
    global MrHezy
    MrHezy = FighterLvl2(Player_Character)
```

Comment: When I make MrHezy global where you say (LevelUp method 2) it has no effect. When I do it on the first LevelUp method it seems to work in leveling up my player to FighterLvl1 I run into the problem with inheritance mentioned in the original post. For some reason FighterLvl1 isnt inheriting all of the attributes from Player_Character, how do I get FighterLvl1 to inherit all the attributes from Player_Character?

Comment: PS when I implement this method it crashes when I attempt to gain exp (because for some reason it wasnt inherited) but I think it is a step in the right direction.

Comment: You need to make MrHeazy global each time you want to change it like that. I just used the level up to level 2 as an  example.

Comment: In terms of the inheritance issue you are having, I assume you are wanting all the instance attributes of Player_Character to be passed on to FighterLevel1 etc. 
To do that you need to actually pass them along.

Answer (score 0):

The level up replaces a variable in the object, what you should do, **if** you want to use a class per level (not necessarily a good idea) is:

Create a `Character` class.

In `Character` class define an `implementation` field.

Initialize `implementation` field e.g. `implementation = SomeSpeciesLevel1()`.

To "level-up": `implementation = implementation.level_up()`

This way you have a constant wrapper that doesn't change which wraps the level-changing implementation.

*A better design would be to have one class with functionality based on level-dependant formulas.*

```python
class CharImpl:
    @abstractmethod
    def can_level_up() -> bool:
        return NotImplemented
    @abstractmethod
    def next_level() -> CharImpl:
        return NotImplemented
    pass

class Character:
    def __init__(initial_impl: CharImpl=None):
        self.impl = initial_impl.copy() if initial_impl else HumanLevel1()
        pass
    def level_up():
        if self.impl.can_level_up():
            self.impl = self.impl.next_level()
        pass
    pass

class Human(CharImpl):
    pass

class HumanLevel1(Human):
    def __init__(src: Human):
        # TODO: copy relevant fields from src
        pass
    def can_level_up() -> bool:
        return True
    def next_level() -> CharImpl:
        return HumanLevel2(self)
    pass

class HumanLevel2(Human):
    def __init__(src: Human):
        # TODO: copy relevant fields
        pass
    def can_level_up() -> bool:
        return False
    def next_level() -> CharImpl:
        return self
    pass
```

Comment: What should I do to level up? can you recommend any reading material? I am unsure how to implement your answer, can you please show me using my code?

Comment: @HezekiahBodine sorry but your code is the problem, you should refactor it. I suggested a pattern you can use with code examples in my answer. I suggest you read about object orient programming and also about functional programming with immutable objects. Also, a class per level is not scalable, instead consider changing other fields based on class e.g. strength, skill, luck etc.

Comment: Im sorry but Im still unable to figure out exactly how to implement your solution. and how is your "implementation field' any different from my 'LevelUp' method?

Comment: can you show me exactly how to implement your method using "Player_Character" as the base class and "FighterLvl1" as the first level?

Comment: @HezekiahBodine see new example

Comment: When I run your new example through my IDE it comes up with 16 errors

Comment: @HezekiahBodine I didn't write this in an IDE, this is an example, not runnable code, however, the syntax looks right, this is of course Python 3 code. I assume that you can fix any small syntax issue I missed while typing here. Also, you should really read a bit of the Python documentation on classes.

Comment: I fixed most of the errors by adding the self argument to all of the methods. However, it still says that @abstractmethod and CharImpl() are unresolved references...

Comment: Search for @abstractmethod to see how to use it, CharImpl is the first class defined in the example, check the upper i vs lower L.

Comment: I eliminated the abstractmethod errors by importing the abc module's ABC and abstractmethod classes, CharImpl in the level up method is still an unresolved reference